# drupal Theme class is missing, I guess! How to fix it?

Tags: theming

[image: screenshot]

I am using civicrm on drupal 7.26. When I use default theme i can see the link "View all Contribution...." but as you can see from top part of screenshot it does not appear on bootstrap theme. can anyone help me to fix this please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your theme has all the appropriate [Theme Regions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!region.tpl.php/7) ([more details about Theme Regions](https://drupal.org/node/171224)). Also, there may be some custom PHP overrides provided by the working theme, so you'll want to review the theme's `template.php` file for any [custom PHP theme overrides](https://drupal.org/node/173880) you may want to help bring over to your other theme.